# Best practice to start with the development of a web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

We (a group of 4 students) are planning to create a web-app on Ruby on Rails. I have done some web app projects in the past and one thing I have learned is the initial time devoted to design the app, which was very less, I just start coding with some basic things in my mind.

So, this time, I don't want to do the same mistake and want to plan the app ([high level design](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sfYaJEU5jsIJ:www.bitformation.com/art/sample_sw_design_doc.doc+high+level+design+doc&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)). But again, sometimes I feel it might be an overkill for a student project which might span for 6 months.

So, what should be the best approach in this case?

My reqs are:

1. A plan which guides us through the development.
2. Should the plan be a text doc, a block diagram or what?
3. Should be clean, crisp and concise.
4. Would be great if you point me to some sample doc, template etc. Which is not an overkill but effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start making a clone for stackoverflow. Dont go for a full deep functionality for initial stage.

1. Divide the whole functionality in 4-5 different phases.
2. Decide your phases.
3. You can use basecamphq(30 days free) or Fogbugz for planing, to-dos and lighthouse for bug tracking.

**EDIT**

Just think about the basic minimal functionality SO has:--

1. Sign-up. (Normal + open-id)
2. Ask a question, answer a question
3. Comments on question and answer
4. Votes on question and answer
5. tag a question
6. Question stats like question views, Unanswered question etc
7. Points
8. Badges etc

   **Make a list and divide them in various phases.  Don't try to make exact thing in one go. Just start from basic things**.

---

Like for the first phase.

1. Sign up
2. Ask question, with tags
3. answer a question
4. comments on them
5. Basic profile page.

---

For next phase:--

1. Add ajax for comments (Good for learning ajax)
2. Votes, Not points
3. Add things like Unanswered questions. (initial dont try to find the logic how SO is listing unanswered questions, Just do something like unanswered questions means question having no answer.)
4. Question views

---

then next phase and next phase. and finally you have a clone. :-)
Ask Jeff to review it. (Kidding)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on points 1 and 2. For example, what can be the phases for a clone of so.com?

Comment: zengr Check edit part. Hoping it makes some sense.

Comment: yup, it sure does. Thanks. you wokring on Shapado?

Comment: No, I just started learning rails 3-4 months before so i just made a stackoverflow clone :-). Not fully furnished but ya quite close to it.